# Use html() as append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use `html()` same as how it works with `append()`

```
function showResponse(response) {
 var $list = $('#list');
 var items = response.items;

 $.each(items, function(id, el){
  $list.html('el.id.videoId')

 });
}
```

I dont know if anyone did understand it but what i want is

```
List1 = id1, id2 id3 
List2 = id4 id5 id6
```

When List1 is listed, and List2 will be requested this must remove List1 and list List2

With append it makes the list just longer, but i want it to replace it with current

Comment: Why use html() as append()? Why not use append() as append()? html() is html(), not append().

Comment: `.html()`. and `.append()` are completely different methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `html()` replaces all the content every time you call it, so you're replacing the content on every iteration.

To only replace the content after the loop has completed you can do

```
function showResponse(response) {
    var $list  = $('#list');
    var items  = response.items;
    var result = "";

    $.each(items, function(id, el){
        result += el.id.videoId;
    });

    $list.html(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this does the list fine like i want it(Y)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$list.html($list.html() + 'el.id.videoId');
```

jQuery.html() returns the current html in object

jQuery.html( data ) sets object html to data

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to use html() when append will do the job.

Empty the list it and append the new elements

```
$list.empty();
$.each(items, function(id, el){
    $list.append("<li>" + id + "</li>");
});
```

If you want to use html(), than build a string with all the list items and set it at once.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
$list.empty().append('el.id.videoId');
```